# Comparable error

Tags: java, eclipse, comparable

Newbie question here. I'm trying to teach myself, and sometimes the solo route can be frustrating.  I'm working a problem in Liang's book Introduction to Java Programming 8th edition (Exercise 14.1) where I have to modify a GeometricObject class to implement Comparable and then define a static "max" method to find the larger of two GeometricObjects.  Then I have to write a test program that uses this max method to find the larger of two rectangles.  Previously in the book, the author has had us create a Rectangle subclass that extends GeometricObject.  I've modified the GeometricObject class to implement Comparable, and I've created the max method.  Then I've modified the Rectangle subclass to also implement Comparable.  I wrote the test program as well.

But Eclipse is giving me the Big Red X by my Rectangle class's declaration saying "The interface Comparable cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments: Comparable and Comparable."  That's when my class declaration looks like this:

```
public class Rectangle extends GeometricObject implements Comparable<Rectangle> {
```

I've tried removing the parameter altogether:

```
public class Rectangle extends GeometricObject implements Comparable {
```

... and the error message changes to "Comparable is a raw type. References to generic type Comparable should be parameterized."  Plus, it adds a second error in this case: "The type Rectangle must implement the inherited abstract method Comparable.compareTo(Object)"

When I look at examples of this kind of declaration, they always seem to use the class name as the parameter for Comparable in the declaration, an in fact, that's what the books say to do.  So why is it saying I can't do that here?

And then what about the second error regarding the compareTo() method?  Why is it only being pointed out when I remove the parameter from the declaration?  Code for the Rectangle class follows (if I need to, I can post the GeometricObject superclass as well):

```
public class Rectangle extends GeometricObject implements Comparable<Rectangle> {
private double width;
private double height;

public Rectangle() {
}

public Rectangle(double width, double height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public Rectangle(double width, double height, String color, boolean filled) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    setColor(color);
    setFilled(filled);
}

public double getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setWidth(double width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public double getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(double height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public double getArea() {
    return width * height;
}

public double getPerimeter() {
    return 2 * (width + height);
}

/** Implement the compareTo method defined in Comparable */
public int compareTo(Rectangle o) {
    if (getArea() > ((Rectangle)o).getArea())
        return 1;
    else if (getArea() < ((Rectangle)o).getArea())
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: What properties/methods are available on `GeometricObject`?  I think the idea is you implement `Comparable` only generically on `GeometricObject` itself in such a way that all subclasses should work as well.

Comment: Whoops.  That first error actually reads "The interface Comparable cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments: Comparable and Comparable<Rectangle>"

Comment: Does GeometricObject implement Comparable?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039844/implementing-comparable-interface-from-abstract-class-with-concrete-subclasses for example.

Comment: public abstract class GeometricObject implements Comparable {
 private String color = "white";
 private boolean filled;
 private java.util.Date dateCreated;....... more code follows..

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow as well, and trying to figure out how to format code in these comments.  I just posted the first part of the GeometricObject class.  Hope it's clear that I've implemented Comparable in that class as well.

Comment: Code in comments won't work very well. However, you can edit your question to add the GeometricObject code there.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks to all of you.  Solution involved leaving the computer and taking my cats outside in the sunshine for a few minutes while thinking about the problem and all of your feedback.  I was over-complicating the whole Comparable interface thing.  Comparable really is just a SIMPLE interface with one method that needs to be overridden.  Once I got that concept, I was able to go back to the code and the convoluted errors really stood out.  The book I'm using hasn't covered generics yet, so that was confusing.  Thanks again to all of you!

Comment: Glad it's fixed.  Remember to upvote/accept comments/answers that helped you, so any future users that see this question can have good insight into the solution!

Comment: Stack won't let me upvote yet because I'm a lowly 6.  It says I have to be a 15 before I can upvote  :-(  But I think it will let me accept.

Comment: It looks like one of the things I was doing wrong was putting the actual class object as the parameter to the compareTo method. When I simply made the parameter (Object o), it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's a bit tricky, and might be confusing.

When you declare GeometricObject to be Comparable that mean that every  GeometricObject can be compared with another GeometricObject- so you can sort list of GeometricObject (probably it will be it's sub-classes instances cause it's probably gonna be abstract).
So when you implement Comparable in GeometricObject you need to implement this function:

```
public int compareTo(GeometricObject o) {}
```

in that point, when extending GeometricObject with Rectangle- Rectangle automatic deriving it's super class compareTo method. and when implement Comparable in Rectangle you need to implement this function:

```
public int compareTo(Rectangle o) {}
```

It's seems like there is no problem, cause it's seems like a regular overloading, but here is the catch- Generics in Java it's just a syntactic sugar for compiler- in run time all generic become Object so after compilation Rectangle going to contains 2 methods that will be the same.

So you have choose only one, although if we take your use case it's probably ok- you can implement only Comparable in super class and in Rectangle override it and check whether it's instance of Rectangle and do your specific logic or use the super class logic.

Answer (score 0):

Since the parent class geometric object is already implementing Comparable you need not implement the same again in the base class 'Rectangle'.

Your base class should look like this

`public class Rectangle extends geometricObject  {
}`

Since geometricObject is implementing Comparable even rectangle class is implementing Comparable. You just need to override the compareTo() method in rectangle class to compare using max method.

Comment: OK, so I removed the implementation of Comparable from the Rectangle object.  At the end of the program, I've overridden the compareTo() method.  But it's not acknowledging that I've done so.  Eclipse is marking my class declaration with an error now that is telling me I have to override compareTo().  Am I overriding it incorrectly?

Comment: Quick tip: For situations like this you can use Eclipe's "Quickfix" feature: Place your cursor on the class name (Eclipse will have marked it with a dotted red line) and press CTRL+1 on Windows or CMD+1 on OSX. Eclispe will than show a popup with a couple of suggestions (depending on the kind of error). In your case, you should choose "Add unimplemented methods". Eclipse will add the missing method(s) and you can check in what way their signature is  different from what you wrote yourself. Maybe this helps to figure something out.